# Recording Freeswitch Conference Using ESL

Tags: recording, freeswitch, conference

I'm trying to initiate the recording of a conference over an ESL connection, but it doesn't seem to work the way I'm trying to do it, but I can't figure out what the right way is.

I'm sending the following command over the wire

```
call-command: execute
execute-app-name: conference
execute-app-arg: 01444b76-c08d-5990-b65c-000100620005 recording start /tmp/conference-01444b76-c08d-5990-b65c-000100620005.ulaw
Event-UUID: 9423a931-8cb7-4010-aad8-3cfb83db4b35
```

However instead of starting to record a conference it creates a conference with then name "01444b76-c08d-5990-b65c-000100620005 recording start /tmp/conference-01444b76-c08d-5990-b65c-000100620005.ulaw". I've also tried sending

```
call-command: execute
execute-app-name: conference 01444b76-c08d-5990-b65c-000100620005 recording start 
execute-app-arg: /tmp/conference-01444b76-c08d-5990-b65c-000100620005.ulaw
Event-UUID: 9423a931-8cb7-4010-aad8-3cfb83db4b35
```

Which results in errors as the command "conference 01444b76-c08d-5990-b65c-000100620005 recording start"

And sending this

```
call-command: execute
execute-app-name: conference
execute-app-arg: 01444b76-c08d-5990-b65c-000100620005, recording, start, /tmp/conference-01444b76-c08d-5990-b65c-000100620005.ulaw
Event-UUID: 9423a931-8cb7-4010-aad8-3cfb83db4b35
```

Which simply results in a conference named "01444b76-c08d-5990-b65c-000100620005, recording, start, /tmp/conference-01444b76-c08d-5990-b65c-000100620005.ulaw"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execute` runs a dialplan application, which is exactly that -- creating a conference. I think you need `api` or `bgapi` to start the recording.

I assume `01444b76-c08d-5990-b65c-000100620005` is the name of an existing conference which is already started by the dialplan application, right?

Comment: Then the api call should do the job.